# Google Cloud Firestore REST API createDocument auto genarates ID

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

This is the REST API call I make to create a new document in my firestore database

> POST https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/[xxx]/databases/(default)/documents/items

Here is the payload that I add to the body of the post method:

```
    {
        "name": "projects/[xxx]/databases/(default)/documents/items/6001156905205",
        "fields": {
            "Name": {
                "stringValue": "Freshpak Rooibos Tea 80Pk"
            },
            "Description": {
                "stringValue": "Enjoy a cup of Freshpak Rooibos your no 1 Rooibos tea.
            }
        },
        "createTime": "2018-02-21T14:20:55.753234Z",
        "updateTime": "2018-02-21T14:20:55.753234Z"
    }
```

I get the below error message:

```
    {
        "error": {
            "code": 400,
            "message": "document.name must not be set",
            "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
        }
    }
```

When I remove the "name" property from the payload it creates the record in firebase but the document Id is then auto generated. I would like the Id to be 6001156905205.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks
Gert

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to specify the document ID that you want to use, as a query parameter, as detailed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/createDocument#query-parameters). The `createTime` and `updateTime` are output only, so they will automatically be set by Cloud Firestore.

#### HTTP Request

```
POST https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/[xxx]/databases/(default)/documents/items?documentId=6001156905205
```

#### Request body

```
{
  "fields": {
    "Name": {
      "stringValue": "Freshpak Rooibos Tea 80Pk"
    },
    "Description": {
      "stringValue": "Enjoy a cup of Freshpak Rooibos your no 1 Rooibos tea.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If this fails, you may need to put your client ID in quotes: `?documentId="6001156905205"`

Comment: @JasonBerryman how do you create a data model for the above json body? My C# code creates StringValue, IntValue as classes. Is there a way that we could convert normal json to firebase acceptable collection json?

Comment: @KhanXc I have no idea.  I'm not familiar with C#.  Apologies that I can't help

Comment: How do you do this if you want to randomly generate a documentId?  Since the document is not created yet I won't have an ID to provide.

Comment: Any UUID library can do this for you