# How to set the Doc Id with Firebase REST API

Tags: python, firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to manually create a docId when inserting a document into Firestore?

The following Python3 code will insert a new document in Firestore with an auto-generated docId.

```
import requests
import json

project_id = 'MY_PROJECT_NAME'
web_api_key = 'MY_WEB_API_KEY'
collection_name = 'MY_COLLECTION_NAME'
url = f'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project_id}/databases/(default)/documents/{collection_name}/?key={web_api_key}'

payload = {
    'fields': {
        'title': { 'stringValue': 'myTitle' },
        'category': { 'stringValue': 'myCat' },
        'temperature': { 'doubleValue': 75 }
    }
}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

response_dict = json.loads(response.content)
for i in response_dict:
    print(f'{i}: {response_dict[i]}')
```

In case anyone else wants to use this code in the future, to get a Web API key, go to Google Cloud Platform > APIs & Services > Credentials > Create Credentials > API key, then copy the value it generates here.

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 4):

answered in [Google Cloud Firestore REST API createDocument auto genarates ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48941368/google-cloud-firestore-rest-api-createdocument-auto-genarates-id) documentId should be added as a query parameter when document is created

So for the code in the question, just url should be changed with the same body:

```
url = f'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project_id}/databases/(default)/documents/{collection_name}?documentId={your_custom_doc_id}&key={web_api_key}'
```

Comment: @Yunnosch You are right, however, would have expected either a comment as above by DIDI Byte or an example to count as a complete answer, but maybe I am wrong and it enriches the options for someone looking for an answer.

Comment: Not saying it is good, only pointing out that a flag on this would probably be declined.

Answer (score 0):

To set a custom document ID, you only need to append the name to the URL path after the respective collection. This is similar to how the document reference works where the path must point to the desired location.

From the documentation:

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/cities/LA
```

Comment: I get the error "error: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Document parent name "projects/fore-3610f/databases/(default)/documents/SensorData" lacks "/" at index 60.', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}".

where I had...

url = f'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project_id}/databases/(default)/documents/SensorData/abc123/?key={web_api_key}'

Comment: works for me: You should double check your path structure and ensure you have `/` where needed

Comment: under normal use, "...databases/(default)/documents/cities/LA" works, but it's not working for the REST API for me

Comment: have you tried without the trailing `/`? reading documentation such as https://engineering.flosports.tv/google-cloud-firestore-document-crud-with-php-1df1c084e45b doesn't display a `/` as being required on the end so it maybe assuming a second path name

Comment: Similar Question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59143680/2301161

Comment: I've tried without the trailing '/', example: 'databases/(default)/documents/SensorData/abc123?key={web_api_key}' still gives a 400 error

Comment: I suspect something else may be going on and will require further debugging.