# Create new firestore document with REST API

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a new document id and store my collection inside it. My post looks like this:

```
{     
 "name": "projects/<project-id>/databases/(default)/documents/users/cena123",

  "fields": {
    "name": {
      "stringValue": "tom"
    },
    "lname": {
      "stringValue": "cruise"
    }
```

ERROR i get:

`error": { "code": 400, "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \" {\r\n      \"name\": \"projects/mountain-bear-****/databases/(default)/documents/users/cena123\",\r\n`

What T'm trying to achieve:

1. Create a document called: "cena123"
2. Add name and lname fields under the document

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Cloud Firestore REST API createDocument auto genarates ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48941368/google-cloud-firestore-rest-api-createdocument-auto-genarates-id)

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. Unfortunately, the solution looks outdated. This is the error i get: The requested URL "/v1beta1/projects/mountain-bear-****/databases/databases/(default)/documents/users?documentId=%22dhanushkkarh%22 was not found on this server. That’s all we know."

Comment: @xcrystal360 you have duplicated databases in the url it should be 
"v1beta1/projects/mountain-bear-****/databases/(default)/documents/users?documentId=dhanushkkarh"

Comment: @MarkMunene yes, rookie mistake :,) However, I'm still encountering an error. Apparently the payload syntax might be wrong. Here is what i get: ```"code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name``` I'd really appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are receiving `"code": 400, "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name` error, is because `name` should not be passed in the request body, unless it's inside the fields object.
Use the below json in your request body.

```
 {
      "fields": {
        "name": {
          "stringValue": "tom"
        },
        "lname": {
          "stringValue": "cruise"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking your time. I just tried this and no luck :( It throws me the exact same error

Comment: ```"message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"{\r\n  \"fields\": {\r\n    \"name\": {\r\n      \"stringValue\": \"tom\"\r\n    },\r\n    \"lname\": {\r\n      \"stringValue\": \"cruise\"\r\n    }\r\n}\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field '{\r\n  \"fields\": {\r\n    \"name\": {\r\n      \"stringValue\": \"tom\"\r\n    },\r\n    \"lname\": {\r\n      \"stringValue\": \"cruise\"\r\n    }\r\n}' could not be found in request message.",```

Comment: This is the message. Does it make any sense to you?

Comment: I forgot the last bracket, I have updated my answer.

Comment: @xcrystal360 It should work now with the updated answer.

Comment: I just tried it and its throwing me the same error. Just to clarify, I'm using firetore database and not realtime database. Do you think there is a schematical error in the request body?

Comment: UPDATE: The problem was with my client. It didn;t parse properly. Your code works perfectly now!!!!!!! Thank you so much. You made my day!!!

Comment: is there any way to bypass field type definition in data payload ("stringValue") . My platform does not provide that flexibility